# Get friends location in a Facebook application

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

Hi I'm working on a Facebook application. It retrieves your friend information(image, age, etc) and also your friends location and presents it on a map. I have got a friends list that gives me all the ID's and names but I have not been able to retrieve their location. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the `user_location` and `friends_location` [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/); double check that you have those from your user with a call to `/me/permissions`

Once you have, it's pretty easy, you can check for an individual user with a call to `/USER_ID_HERE?fields=location` and for a bunch of users together with a call to `/?ids=CSV_LIST_OF USER_IDS&fields=location`

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for answer. still can't get it could you write a small example please?

Comment: What problem are you having? I tested my own code just now with an access token from the Graph API Explorer `( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer )` and it worked for me

Comment: I have got a permissions for the user location and friend location. when i do that it gives me only Array
(
    [505450713] => Array
        (
            [id] => 505450713
            [name] => Pem Chhoden Tshering
            [first_name] => Pem
            [middle_name] => Chhoden
            [last_name] => Tshering
            [link] => http://www.facebook.com/pem.c.tshering
            [username] => pem.c.tshering
            [gender] => female
            [locale] => en_GB
        )

)

Comment: then it gives Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [message] => (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: <505450713>?fields=location
            [type] => OAuthException
            [code] => 803
        )

)

Comment: The '<>' wasn't supposed to be literal, sorry, i'll edit the answer, it should look like `/12345?fields=location`

Comment: That user might not have a location set by the way, which is easily possible, check the full friends list to see what percentage of the user's friends have a location set, i'd guess it's about 60-80% based on a quick check of my own friends list

Comment: still gives me this error  Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [message] => (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: /505450713?fields=location
            [type] => OAuthException
            [code] => 803
        )

)

Comment: yes i know that why i am trying to get the location of one friend just to get it done then i will think about rest

Comment: That's weird; is the SDK you're using encoding the ?fields= part somehow so that it's not being passed as a GET parameter, but instead being interpreted as part of the ID? check it out in the graph api explorer, it should work.

Comment: yep i cheked it in explorer it works fine

Comment: @Igy, shouldn't `fields` be preceded by `&`? also the Graph API Explorer is going crazy when I try something like: `?ids=XXX,YYY&fields=birthday` (showing the metadata even without setting it!)

Comment: mm thanks it works but not with location!( how to do it for location?

Comment: @ifaour: Graph API Explorer always shows metadata by silently adding &metadata=1 to all queries

Comment: @Igy, but then it should show these info in the right sidebar (*Connections* and *Fields*)? not in the main area?

Comment: It should, but some fields aren't stripped out when the response comes back and appear along with the rest of the data; the tool is not aware of all possible metadata

Comment: yes when i go to Facebook explorer it shows me connection and fields permissions on the right sidebar

Comment: but when write in my php "?ids=xxxxx&fields=location"   it doesn't work

Comment: Works for me, are you sure you have the right permissions? Check with a call to /me/permissions

Comment: i checked it and it gives me that  {
   "data": [
      {
        
         
         "friends_hometown": 1,
         "friends_location": 1,
         "friends_likes": 1,
         "friends_activities": 1,
         "friends_interests": 1,
         "friends_education_history": 1,
         "friends_work_history": 1,
         "friends_online_presence": 1,
         "friends_website": 1,
         "friends_groups": 1,
         
      }
   ]
}

Comment: no i have got a user_location as well i just didn't putted cease not enough space

Comment: is that possible to contact through the Skype or something else?